# Set variable value from Select statement in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, variables, select, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm very new to PL/SQL. And I have the following code:

```
 BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
    schedule_name   => 'By_Days_Of_Weak_Schedule',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=weekly; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED');
END;
//Schedule created

create or replace 
PROCEDURE set_intervals_procedure (
    to_task_id   in number,
    repetitions_count   in number)

AS  
                interval_string   VARCHAR2(255);
                start_d           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
                return_date_after TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
                next_run_date     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE; 
BEGIN                             
               Select START_DATE Into start_d From DBA_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES 
                        WHERE SCHEDULE_NAME = 'BY_DAYS_OF_WEAK_SCHEDULE';

               Select REPEAT_INTERVAL Into interval_string From DBA_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES 
                        WHERE SCHEDULE_NAME = 'BY_DAYS_OF_WEAK_SCHEDULE';

                return_date_after := start_d;
                FOR i IN 1..repetitions_count LOOP
                  DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING(  
                     interval_string,
                    start_d, return_date_after, next_run_date);                                                                

                return_date_after := next_run_date;
                END LOOP;         
END set_intervals_procedure;
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile. It ignores my Select statements, though they are correct. Could someone possibly tell me where I'm mistaken. 
Thanks

Comment: do you have the select permission on DBA_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES ?

Comment: What error(s) do you get from the compilation? (`show errors`, or `select * from user_errors`). And following on from @schurik's comment, if you do have select permission, is it granted directly to you or via a role?

Comment: It is granted via a role, because separately from other code these select statements work fine and generally I can derive info from my schedule. I have the following mistakes:                                                 Error(11,16): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(11,52): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error(14,16): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(14,65): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: it must be granted direct,  or use AUTHID CURRENT_USER

Comment: I think this is not the reason because they work outside this procedure and having written the following: Grant All On BY_DAYS_OF_WEAK_SCHEDULE to Dima;     nothing has changed - mistakes stayed the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dba\_jobs\_running: table or view does not exist when trying to access from procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968857/dba-jobs-running-table-or-view-does-not-exist-when-trying-to-access-from-proced)

Comment: @Dima - you need to `grant select on dba_scheduler_schedules to dima`, not to your specific schedule. Or see if you can use `user_scheduler_schedules` instead, which might be more appropriate anyway.